# How to replace certain elements of a NumPy array via an index array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an numpy array `a` that I would like to replace some elements. I have the value of the new elements in a tuple/numpy array and the indexes of the elements of `a` that needs to be replaced in another tuple/numpy array. Below is an example of using python to do what I want.How do I do this efficiently in NumPy?

**Example script:**

```
a = np.arange(10)
print( f'a = {a}' )
newvalues = (10, 20, 35)
indexes = (2, 4, 6)
for n,i in enumerate( indexes ):
    a[i]=newvalues[n]
print( f'a = {a}' )
```

Output:

```
a =  array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
a =  array([ 0,  1, 10,  3, 20,  5, 35,  7,  8,  9])
```

I tried `a[indexes]=newvalues` but got `IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 3 were indexed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of indices indicating which elements you want to replace should be a Python `list` (or similar type), not a `tuple`. Different items in the selection tuple indicate that they should be selected from different axis dimensions.

Therefore, `a[(2, 4, 6)]` is the same as `a[2, 4, 6]`, which is interpreted as the value at index 2 in the first dimension, index 4 in the second dimension, and index 6 in the third dimension.

The following code works correctly:

```
indexes = [2, 4, 6]
a[indexes] = newvalues
```

See also [the page on Indexing from the numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html), specifically the second 'Note' block in the introduction as well as the first 'Warning' under [Advanced Indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

> In Python, `x[(exp1, exp2, ..., expN)]` is equivalent to `x[exp1, exp2, ..., expN]`; the latter is just syntactic sugar for the former.

> The definition of advanced indexing means that `x[(1,2,3),]` is fundamentally different than `x[(1,2,3)]`. The latter is equivalent to `x[1,2,3]` which will trigger basic selection while the former will trigger advanced indexing. Be sure to understand why this occurs.

Comment: For `newvalues`, does it matter if it is a `list`, `tuple` or `numpy.array`?

Comment: @SunBear I think you can use any data type that you can also use in `np.array()`.

Comment: The list of indices indicating which elements I want, i.e. `indexes`, can also be an `numpy.array()`.